# Why does actioncable in Rails 5 require a backing database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Maybe this is a dumb question but I am curious why a websockets library would require either Redis or Postgres?

For everything I would use it for I don't have any reason to need that data saved to disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not to save data.
It's for the queueing system ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue )

Websocket with Rails require a queue to exchange messages between your subscribers and publishers. Subscribers get messages put in the queue by a publisher.

If you take a look at redis, it's in memory, no data save on the disk.

Hope it help.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't know redis was a memory store. I would upvote you if I could. Thanks.